# Blender always selects the shortest path when selecting vertices how do I turn this off?

Tags: selection-tools

[image: Image containing the problem] When I select vertices blender selects the vertices connecting the desired vertices as well. I also notices it states: "Pick shortest path" in the bottem left. I'm quite new to blender and haven't found anything online about this. I hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Blender's behavior will pick the shortest path (eg. everything between point "A" THRU "Z") if you hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on your next selection.

If you use <kbd>Shift</kbd> instead, then it will just append the selected item to the set of items selected (eg. Just point "A" & "Z").